# Sliding Window Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, pseudocode, sliding-window

**I know that the time complexity of the sliding window algorithm is o(N) but what is the time complexity of a variable-sized sliding window algorithm.**

For eg-

array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

when size of sliding window is = 1
**window - [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]**

when size of sliding window is = 2
**window - [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5], [5,6]**

when size of sliding window is = 3
**window - [1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4,5,6]**

and so on ...

**window size will range from 1 to n (valid values for window size). If creating a single-window costs O(N) then creating N windows will cost O(N^2)?**

Comment: Is the variable for the window size also a parameter? Looks like O(n) regardless. The question is: how many times do you visit `array[i]` for any `i`? The answer is 2 in all window sizes, once when pushed onto the head of the window, one when dequeued from the tail.

Comment: The algorithm that uses the sliding window will be O(n) regardless of the size of the sliding window.

Comment: window size will range from 1 to n (valid values for a window). If creating a single-window costs O(N) then creating N windows will cost O(N^2)?

Comment: If you want to make a window of size `n` then you get a single sliding window. Why would it be `O(n^2)`?

Comment: @VLAZ No, the size of the window varies from 1 to n (both inclusive).

Comment: Yes, but for an array of size `n`, a sliding window of size `n` is...one window. That contains the entire array.

Comment: Which "the" sliding window algorithm are you referring to ? A sliding median filter (for instance) does not have O(N) complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a sliding window across an array is O(n) regardless of the size of the window.

The head pointer and tail pointers increase monotonically for all window sizes. In contrast, a typical nested loop quadratic algorithm runs the inner index `j` from `i` to `n` for every outer index `i`.

The assumption here is that you're not doing any extra work besides the deque offers and polls (which are constant time for each `i`) such as looping over the window for every `i`.

If you're creating `n` windows from `1` to `n`, you're back to the classical nested-loop quadratic algorithm, O(n^2).